# Uncaught TypeError: setLoading is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to pass a React hook to react-redux. I pass in `loading` and `setLoading` hook. However, when I try to use `setLoading` I get an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: setLoading is not a function`

I'm really not sure what I am misunderstanding but I am new to React and even newer to react-redux. I am using `mapStateToProps` but can't figure out how to use Hooks with it.

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

export const CustomForm = ({ loading, setLoading, doAction }) => {
  const onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    doAction("finish", setLoading)
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <form onSubmit={onClick}>
            <Button type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
        </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loading: state.loading,
    setLoading: state.setLoading
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    doAction: (action, setLoading) => dispatch(action, setLoading),
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CustomForm)
```

Here is how I call `CustomForm`:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
<CustomForm loading={loading} setLoading={setLoading} />
```

EDIT: I need loading and setLoading defined outside the component because I use them outside of the component also.

Comment: Where and how do you define `setLoading`?

Comment: So the error isn't a React or Redux one, it's just a Javascript one. In the parent of `CustomForm` how are you defining `setLoading`?

Comment: I am defining `setLoading` as a Hook from the container that holds the form: `const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);`

Comment: In your `CustomForm` component declare a function as such: `update(nextState) { setLoading(nextState);}` pass in this method instead into the `CustomForm` component, like this:
`<CustomForm loading={loading} setLoading={update} />`.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer I get the same error with that

Comment: Hmm, I perhaps said wrong.. don't write the `update(nextState) ` function in the `CustomForm` component. Write it in the component where `const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);` is being used.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was a pretty silly mistake. Incase someone faces it, it may help.

So I was doing this

```
const {loading, setLoading} = useState(false);
```

instead of this:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

Keep an eye on the curly brackets and square brackets. I mistakenly typed the curly braces

Answer (score 1):

I had same doubt as [@BlackMath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10134463/blackmath), later I found you have defined it in last.

1. A better way would be, directly define it inside your component.
2. and, we cant call the callback function like this `doAction("finish", setLoading)` if it is taking any parameter. since, `setLoading` is expecting a value `true` or `false`.

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

export const CustomForm = ({ doAction }) => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

  const onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    doAction("finish", ()=>{ 
      setLoading(false); //or true based on your logic
    })
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <form onSubmit={onClick}>
            <Button type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
        </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loading: state.loading,
    setLoading: state.setLoading
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    doAction: (action, setLoading) => dispatch(action, setLoading),
  }
}
```

Comment: I need it defined outside the component because I use it outside of the component also.

Comment: yes. That might be the case. additional info, try to use useContext also in your code.